# Django kind of overloaded views

Tags: django, parameters, django-views, overloading

How is this possible to make overloaded views in Django ?
The problem is I have a view which may accept exactly one argument or none.
If there is a argument, it will pass it to view.

Let show what I am tryin' to do

**views.py**

```
def member_list(request,message):
    memberList = Member.objects.all()
    return render_response(request, 'user/member_list.html', {'memberList': memberList,    'message':message })

def member_list(request,message):
    memberList = Member.objects.all()
    return render_response(request, 'user/member_list.html', {'memberList': memberList,    'message':message })
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^member/list/$', 'views.member_list'),
(r'^member/list/(?P<message>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.member_list'),
```

What is the right way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def member_list(request,message=None):
    if message:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use optional arguments in your view signature to your advantage here.

Simply define your view like this:

```
def member_list(request, message=None):
```

And then if there's a match in the URL,  it'll get filled in.  If not, it will still be `None`.

```
if message is None:
    # I got here via the '^member/list/$' URL regex
else:
    # I got here via the '^member/list/(?P<message>[-\w]+)/$' URL regex
```

(Adapted from [this blog post](http://lethain.com/using-optional-parameters-in-django-urls/))